# How to add query results to prometheus alert manager description

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

When an alert goes out from prometheus alert manager, specifically when my disks are filling up I would like to know the size of the disk as well as the space that is left on the disk. I am trying to add a template query to the alert description and I have the following alert rule

```
      - alert: Disk_space_80_percent_full
    expr: |
      100 - ((node_filesystem_avail{device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"} * 100 ) / node_filesystem_size{device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"}) > 80
    for: 5m
    labels:
      alert_policy: "warning" 
      alert_receiver: "slack"
    annotations:
      summary: "Disk space is above 80% full"
      description: |
        "
        available = {{ printf `node_filesystem_avail{instance="%s",device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"}` $labels.instance | query | first }}
        disk size = {{ printf `node_filesystem_size{instance="%s",device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"}` $labels.instance | query | first }}
        "
```

However this is not giving me the results I want. It is returning what looks like a tuple

```
{
map[
    _name__:node_filesystem_size 
    device:/dev/nvme0n1p1 
    env:dev 
    fstype:ext4 
    instance:<redacted>
    mountpoint:/ 
] 
1.040835129344e+12
```

}

What I really want is that last value I `1.040835129344e+12` how can I refactor my query to show that value only.

Comment: Did you try `{{ ... | query | first |value }}` ?

Comment: Note that if you rewrite the `expr`, you can avoid one querry: `node_filesystem_avail{device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"} < (0.2 * node_filesystem_size{device=~"/dev/nvme.+|/dev/xvd.+"})` will return the size of available disk.

Comment: Actually I did end up trying that and it worked.